# MSI Install fails to install ODBC driver: Custom Action Server Rejected - Wrong Context

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My application uses a MSI installer created with WiX.  I have a customer that is unable to run my installer on their Windows Server 2012 R2 server that is setup with the Terminal Server role.  The install log reports the error message: "Custom Action Server rejected - Wrong Context"

```
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:26:121]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallODBC,Description=Installing ODBC components,)
Action 10:07:26: InstallODBC. Installing ODBC components
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:26:122]: Executing op: ODBCInstallDriver(DriverKey=AgWare Cache Driver,Component={BA124A73-5BF5-5263-9890-E7F0434F664B},Folder=c:\Program Files (x86)\AgWare\UAAR DataLog\,Attribute_=Driver,Value_=edbodbc.dll)
1: AgWare Cache Driver 2: {BA124A73-5BF5-5263-9890-E7F0434F664B} 3: c:\Program Files (x86)\AgWare\UAAR DataLog\ 4: Driver 5: edbodbc.dll 6: Setup 7: edbodbc.dll 
MSI (s) (4C:84) [10:07:26:123]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (4C:84) [10:07:26:125]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 23664 (0x5C70).
MSI (s) (4C:80) [10:07:26:155]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (4C:80) [10:07:26:159]: Custom Action Server rejected - Wrong Context
MSI (s) (4C:84) [10:07:26:162]: CA Server Process has terminated.
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:26:164]: Failed to get IMsiCustomAction*
Action ended 10:07:26: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

I have found this security bulletin from Microsoft that changed some MSI behavior that could be affecting me:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072630

What I can't seem to find is how to change to my installer to work around this issue.  There are some workarounds to removing the turning off the security patch.  I don't want to do that.  I want to fix my installer so this is not an issue.

My install seems to run fine in other locations Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10 are all OK.  I also have a 2012 R2 test server that is not setup with the terminal services role.  I can install there without issue.

My WiX code is very simple:

```
<Component Id="C.edbodbc.dll" Guid="*">
  <File Id="F.edbodbc.dll" Source="..\runtime resources\edbodbc.dll" KeyPath="yes" >
    <ODBCDriver Id="ODBC_ELEVATEDB" Name="AgWare Cache Driver" />
  </File>
</Component>
```

I'm not even sure what I could change in the setup code to make any difference.

Here is one other part of the log file dealing with the ODBC install.  I can't tell if this is relevant or not.  This is in the log prior to the error logged above.

```
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:589]: Doing action: SetODBCFolders
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:589]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 10:07:21: SetODBCFolders. Initializing ODBC directories
Action start 10:07:21: SetODBCFolders.
MSI (s) (4C:84) [10:07:21:591]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (4C:84) [10:07:21:593]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 27244 (0x6A6C).
MSI (s) (4C:FC) [10:07:21:619]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (4C:80) [10:07:21:621]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:623]: LocalSQLInstallDriverEx returned 1 in remote context.
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:623]: For 32-bit 'AgWare Cache Driver' the ODBC API returned 0.  rgchPathOut = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64', dwOldUsage = 0
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:623]: ODBCINSTALLDIR folder has not been set.
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:623]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ODBCTranslator 
MSI (s) (4C:24) [10:07:21:623]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: ODBCTranslator 4: SELECT `ComponentId`,`Description`,`Directory_`, `ActionRequest`, `Installed`, `Attributes` FROM `ODBCTranslator`, `Component` WHERE `ODBCTranslator`.`Component_` = `Component` AND (`ActionRequest` = 1 OR `ActionRequest` = 2) 
Action ended 10:07:21: SetODBCFolders. Return value 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your custom action definition, so we don't know if it's impersonated or not, but I think you should look at the TerminalServerAware setting in custom actions to see if it's what you need.

Comment: My custom action table in the generated msi file is blank.  (well not technically blank it includes a WixUIPrintEual row but I don't think that applies).  I do have an entry in the ODBCDriver table with my ID and Name.  I was assuming the custom action I saw in the log file was an MSI custom action.  I'm not sure where to look for more information on that.

Comment: ok, my answer may be irrelevant. You may be using the ODBCDriver table and other ODBCxxx tables in the MSI file. The issue could be per user vs per machine on a TS system.